# How to delete the whole directory which is not empty?

Tags: erlang

I want to clean the temporary for collecting resource. 
The `file` module only has del_dir/1 which require the directory is empty. But there is not function the get the all files in the directory (with absolute path")

The source code is as follows, how to correct it?

```
 delete_path(X)->
    {ok,List} = file:list_dir_all(X), %% <--- return value has no absolute path here
    lager:debug("_229:~n\t~p",[List]),
    lists:map(fun(X)->
                      lager:debug("_231:~n\t~p",[X]),
                        ok = file:delete(X)
                end,List),
    ok = file:del_dir(X),
    ok.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete a directory via console command using os:cmd, though it's a rough approach. For unix-like OS it will be:

```
os:cmd("rm -Rf " ++ DirPath).
```

If you want to delete a non-empty directory using appropriate erlang functions you have to do it recursively. The following example from [here](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=Delete_a_File) shows how to do it:

```
-module(directory).
-export([del_dir/1]).

del_dir(Dir) ->
   lists:foreach(fun(D) ->
                    ok = file:del_dir(D)
                 end, del_all_files([Dir], [])).

del_all_files([], EmptyDirs) ->
   EmptyDirs;
del_all_files([Dir | T], EmptyDirs) ->
   {ok, FilesInDir} = file:list_dir(Dir),
   {Files, Dirs} = lists:foldl(fun(F, {Fs, Ds}) ->
                                  Path = Dir ++ "/" ++ F,
                                  case filelib:is_dir(Path) of
                                     true ->
                                          {Fs, [Path | Ds]};
                                     false ->
                                          {[Path | Fs], Ds}
                                  end
                               end, {[],[]}, FilesInDir),
   lists:foreach(fun(F) ->
                         ok = file:delete(F)
                 end, Files),
   del_all_files(T ++ Dirs, [Dir | EmptyDirs]).
```

Comment: Probably a wise idea is to avoid hard-coding the path separator (`++ "/" ++`), but to use `filename:join/1` instead. This would preserve portability of the solution, which I guess is the main point against using `os:cmd/1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with the latest version of Erlang/OTP (unreleased, yet), using the `file:del_dir/2` API.

Available options:

- **recursive**: recursively delete the contents of a directory before deleting the directory itself
- **force**: ignore errors when accessing or deleting files or directories
- **keeptop**: the top-most directory is not deleted

Source: https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2565

Answer (score 0):

A different approach in Erlang (the only real reason for using is to maintain platform independence):

```
-spec rm_rf(file:filename()) -> ok.

rm_rf(Dir) ->
    Paths = filelib:wildcard(Dir ++ "/**"),
    {Dirs, Files} = lists:partition(fun filelib:is_dir/1, Paths),
    ok = lists:foreach(fun file:delete/1, Files),
    Sorted = lists:reverse(lists:sort(Dirs)),
    ok = lists:foreach(fun file:del_dir/1, Sorted),
    file:del_dir(Dir).
```

The example above makes a few assumptions about the current directory in relation to the target directory -- if this is an issue for your use it may be advisable to explicitly set a working directory and fully qualify the path to the target.

It is worth noting that a similar approach can be used to recursively copy directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since Erlang OTP 23.0 you can use [file:del_dir_r/1](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#del_dir-1) function.

```
file:del_dir_r(File).
```

**For the ones still using older Erlang versions**, here there is, a replacement based on the source code of the new official del_dir_r fixed to work with older versions:

```
%% Include file.hrl to have access to #file_info{} record
-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").

-spec del_dir_r(File) -> ok | {error, Reason} when
      File :: file:name_all(),
      Reason :: file:posix() | badarg.

del_dir_r(File) ->
    case file:read_link_info(File) of
    {ok, #file_info{type = directory}} ->
        case file:list_dir_all(File) of
        {ok, Names} ->
            lists:foreach(fun(Name) ->
                      del_dir_r(filename:join(File, Name))
                  end, Names);
        {error, _Reason} -> ok
        end,
        file:del_dir(File);
    {ok, _FileInfo} -> file:delete(File);
    {error, _Reason} = Error -> Error
    end.
```